# StringRef to "Value *" conversion

Tags: llvm

How to get the LHS of an instruction in "Value *" format?

Eg: %mul = mul i32 %0, %0

When I use getName() method to retrieve 'mul', I get it in "StringRef" format and I am not able to typecast it to "Value *".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instruction is a subclass of Value. So, you do not need anything to typecast it to Value. Note that the code is (mostly) in SSA form, so the instruction itself defines the resulting value. Check the inheritance diagram at http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html.